# Exponential Smoothing MMdM model

Tags: time-series

What are the equations that describe a multiplicative error multiplicative damped trend multiplicative seasonal $(M, M_d, M)$ model? Where can I find all ets models and their equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyndman is your man, and has conveniently put his textbook with Athana­sopou­los online for free.  See table 7.8 here: https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/6